# What does mysqli_stmt_fetch in php do?

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I don't understand the concept of the fetch function.

I am doing a tutorial from 'PHP Solutions' book and i am using MySQL Improved to update something in the database.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT article_id, title, article FROM journal WHERE article_id = ?';
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['article_id']);                    
$stmt->bind_result($article_id, $title, $article); 
//execute the query, and fetch the result
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->fetch();
```

So what is the fetch actually doing? I thought the execute() function is sending the information to the database and then it returns a true/false value to the $OK variable.

Is fetch() storing something in $stmt? Anybody have any idea what it is doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_fetch` fetches the current row from the resultset and assigns the row values to variables *previously bound to the prepared statement* with [mysqli_stmt_bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Which means that you must call `$stmt->bind_result(...);` first, as it can be seen in the example from the [man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Note that nowadays using `mysqli_stmt_fetch` is considered inconvenient. Either use `mysqli_stmt_get_result` followed by familiar `mysqli_fetch_*` functions, or even avoid the entire bind param hassle with [mysqli_execute_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php).

Comment: It wasn't you, but someone else, there a lot of people here which tends to down-vote without any explanation, just because they don't like the answer or it seems to them not correct.

Comment: oh, i see. i'll give you one more then for your troubles

Comment: thanks, you didn't need to be bothered by this. after several time you get used to it. ;o)

Comment: Link seems to be dead. It would be great if you added some other information to this answer (though it's been 11 years since you replied).